Drawing frames in Drake VIsualizer in c++
I am using DrakeVisualizer to visualise my environment and would like to visualise the joint frames. I use the command python3 -m pydrake.visualization.meldis in a terminal to open the visualiser.
I came across this link drake-how-to-visualize-frame-in-lcm, but was unable to understand how to do it in c++. I am using drake as an external library. Additionally I tried to use Meshcat :

  geometry::MeshcatVisualizerd::AddToBuilder(
      &builder, scene, std::make_shared<geometry::Meshcat>());

But there was nothing displayed in the visualisation.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Have you tried using ModelVisualizer? https://drake.mit.edu/pydrake/pydrake.visualization.model_visualizer.html.
